# A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, image, uploading

A have an image upload function that works fine on localhost but when I try and run under Windows Server 2003 I get the error message

This is the code..

Now before anyone jumps on me ;) I've looked at the previous answers and I've checked all permissions and they seem to be correct.. the folder/paths exist, etc..

```
ImageService imageService = new ImageService();

if (fileBase != null && fileBase.ContentLength > 0 && fileBase.ContentLength <= 2097152 && fileBase.ContentType.Contains("image/"))
{
    var uploadedPath = "~/Assets/Images/";

    Path.GetExtension(fileBase.ContentType);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileBase.FileName);

    if (extension.ToLower() != ".jpg" && extension.ToLower() != ".gif") // only allow these types
    {
        photoViewModel.ImageValid = "Not Valid";
        ModelState.AddModelError("Photo", "Wrong Image Type");
        return View(photoViewModel);
    }

    EncoderParameters encodingParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encodingParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = imageService.GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
    var uploadedimage = Image.FromStream(fileBase.InputStream, true, true);

    Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(uploadedimage);
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(originalImage, 274, 354);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);

    var streamLarge = new MemoryStream();
    newImage.Save(streamLarge, jpgEncoder, encodingParameters);

    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(extension);
    string newname;
    if (photoViewModel.photoURL != null)
    { newname = photoViewModel.photoURL; }
    else
    { newname = Guid.NewGuid() + fileExtension; }

    var ImageName = newname;
    newImage.Save(Server.MapPath(uploadedPath) + ImageName);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(uploadedPath) + ImageName, streamLarge.ToArray());

    photoViewModel.uploadedPath = uploadedPath;
    photoViewModel.photoURL = ImageName;

    originalImage.Dispose();
    newImage.Dispose();
    streamLarge.Dispose();
    return View(photoViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I know you said don't jump, but just to rule out the possibility of bad permissions could you just try writing a test file (any content) in the same location.

Comment: If you getting error message, so please add what message you getting

Comment: @Reniuz : A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: Added write permission for Network service account? Found some details about your problem [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2009/02/28/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception.aspx)

Comment: I've just tried that thanks Reniuz, but it hasn't resolved the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Image.FromStream`, the stream must remain open for the lifetime of the image. That means if the stream is a file, the file will be held open. I think you'll need to dispose uploadedImage to allow the stream to be closed (if you wait for the GC to clean up the uploadedImage, this will occur at an indeterminate point in the future - or may not occur at all).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it (it's using a sledgehammer to crack a nut). Just dispose it when it's not needed.